# Show or Preview pdf file before download in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want show/preview pdf file before download, i try code below,but doesn't work

controller 1 :

```
public function download($id)
    {

        $filesss = Download::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $pathToFile = public_path('uploads/dokumen/' . $filesss->dokumen);
        return response()->file($pathToFile);
    }
```

controller 2 :

```
 public function download($id)
    {

        $filesss = Download::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $filename = 'test.pdf';

        $file = public_path('uploads/dokumen/' . $filesss->dokumen);

        $response = Response::download($file);

        return $response;
    }
```

the two codes above doesn't work

**UPDATE!!**

**done!!... the problem is caused by browser settings. thank you all for your answer**

Comment: If file is too large, may be your browser can't display it